# JSF Facelets - for Non Technical Person

Tags: jsf, facelets

I don't know If this is the right place to ask this question.

How do I make some non technical person to understand `"Facelets as View technology"?`

Answer (score 0):

I try it.
If you use JSF as presentation layer you can use the advantages of input validation for forms, have a direct data binding to one or more ManagedBeans also known as PoJos with annotation @ManagedBean or @Model/@Named...

JSF components also support the usage of Ajax, so you can update tableviews asynchronous after adding new entries for example.

summarizing in my opinion it is easier to built a modern feeling site by using JSF, there are many different implementations e.g. primefaces, richfaces, etc. so you have the choice which framework you'll use.

Hope this helps, maybe the community can add more.
Patrick